# Asp.Net Panel Issue

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, .net

[image: Sample Image]

While Clicking on that textbox panel will activated but it is showing like not in top or front of the screen.
give any solution thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Where is your Code, post the code to find the solution.